# Is this a model of $(\infty, \infty)$?

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Please pardon me if this idea is silly. But could we produce a model for $\infty$ categories by allowing simplices with compatible orientation?

Let me elaborate. One can think of simplicial sets as glued together by simplices with oriented edges with no loops. If we allow looped triangles, it seems that this can produce a way to orient 2 cells. Similarly, oriented 2 cells which are oriented compatibly can be used to define oriented 3 cells and so on. I haven't checked the details, but can something like this work? If so, is there literature on this?

Comment: [Weak complicial sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+complicial+set) are supposed to present $(\infty,\infty)$-categories. This is not quite what you suggested, but I think this notion is closest to your idea among existing in the literature.

Comment: It seems like composition is not encoded in your model. This is why one usually assumes that the models satisfy certain lifting properties (like in quasi-categories or (weak) complicial sets).

Comment: Yes I do agree you need a lot of horn filling conditions which I didn't add. I think this part is OK because we can ask for similarly oriented cells to compose. I'm worried though because even if this produces non invertible 2 cells it's not clear it can produce non invertible 2 cells between two 1 cells going in the same direction, which seems very unfortunate. I'm probably going to close this question

Comment: So i must correct the post to say not only do we allow loops, all cells should have an orientation given by a compatible choice of orientation on the faces, which can be different to the orientations of the faces themselves. This seems to be more plausible

Comment: I don't understand the idea. Simplices are already oriented, so I don't see what kind of modifications you are suggesting here. What is missing to simplicial sets to represented (infinity,n) for n>1 is a way to expres that a given n-cell (n>1) is "an isomorphisms" or an "identity". For example if your 2-cell are not always invertible, how do you express that the composite of two 1-cell f,g is h ? Fixing this problem is what Complicial sets are about.

Comment: @SimonHenry if we think of the standard orientation of simplices as giving orientation to the edges which has no cycles. Maybe it's possible to drop the condition of not having cycles and to ask for higher cells to have orientations which can be incompatible with the face orientations. I don't claim I can modify the construction of simplicial sets easily to get these properties. But geometrically is this a valid way to think about higher morphisms being invertible

Comment: It should be possible to ask for a 2 cell in both orientations being inverses to each other to express the composition? At least intuitively?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. So you would need to allows cells where each faces comes with choice of orientation... I guess it might be possible, but it is hard to say without specifying precisely what would be the combinatorics of your category of cells (you will need to define the degeneracies if you do not use a marking as with complicial cells, and these will be tricky) and a LOT of work...